# Remove entries with multiple associations in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

Given a dataframe of the form:

```
id name

1  a
1  b
2  c
2  a
2  d
3  a
3  d
4  a
```

Here, say "`a`" is associated with more than 3 (arbitrary) IDs. So the result should look something like this: (Remove all `names` with more than 3 associations)

```
id name

1  b
2  c
2  d
3  d
```

How should I go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Group by `name` and count unique `id`
- Filter with compress to limit just those that are less than or equal to 3
- Find only those names that are in compressed names

---

```
u = df.groupby(['name']).id.nunique()
df[df.name.isin(u.compress(lambda x: x <= 3).index)]

   id name
1   1    b
2   2    c
4   2    d
6   3    d
```